# Creating pagination in react using an api

Tags: reactjs, redux, pagination, axios

I am working on creating pagination from pagination react-js-pagination for my first time and I have been able to build the component and get the data back, displayed and functional for what it needs to do, but I receive a maximum of 500 pieces of data from my api and displaying 500 pieces of data on one page is not ideal, hence pagination. I was attempting to slice the data away from the api like so,

```
  render() { 


      let { trailsList, chooseTrail } = this.props;
      console.log(trailsList)

      //FOR PAGINATION
      var indexOfLastTrail = this.state.activePage * this.state.itemPerPage;
      var indexOfFirstTrail = indexOfLastTrail - this.state.itemPerPage;
      var renderedTrails = trailsList.slice(indexOfFirstTrail, indexOfLastTrail);

      console.log(renderedTrails)
    let mappedTrails = renderedTrails ?  renderedTrails.map((trail, index) => {
        return 
        <div className='trailsContainer'> 
            <Link onClick={() => chooseTrail(trail.id)} className='trailButton' to={{ pathname:`/trail/${trail.id}`}} 
         key={index}><div>



        <img id='trailImg' src={trail.imgSmall} alt={trail.name}></img>
        <h4>{trail.name}</h4>
        <h6>Length: {trail.length + ' miles'}</h6>
        <h6>{trail.location}</h6>

        </div></Link>
        </div>
    }) : 'loading'
```

and map the sliced data to be rendered. I return the mapped data and no data was being rendered and my console was still returning that I had 500 pieces of data from that sliced data. Not sure where to go from here as finding information on pagination using an api.

Here is my full component

```
class Trails extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={
        activePage:1,
        itemsPerPage: 20
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
axios.get(`https://www.hikingproject.com/data/get-trails? 
lat=${this.props.location.state.latitude}&lon=
${this.props.location.state.longitude}&maxDistance=150
&maxResults=500&key={API KEY}`).then((res)=> {
    console.log(res.data)
    this.props.getTrails(res.data.trails)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error, 'There was an error finding the trails 
requested.')
    })
  }


handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
    console.log(`active page is ${pageNumber}`);
    this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
  }




  render() { 


      let { trailsList, chooseTrail } = this.props;
      console.log(trailsList)

      //FOR PAGINATION
      var indexOfLastTrail = this.state.activePage * 
this.state.itemPerPage;
      var indexOfFirstTrail = indexOfLastTrail - 
this.state.itemPerPage;
      var renderedTrails = trailsList.slice(indexOfFirstTrail, 
indexOfLastTrail);

      console.log(renderedTrails)
    let mappedTrails = renderedTrails ?  renderedTrails.map((trail, 
index) => {
        return 
        <div className='trailsContainer'> 
            <Link onClick={() => chooseTrail(trail.id)} 
className='trailButton' to={{ pathname:`/trail/${trail.id}`}} 
         key={index}><div>



        <img id='trailImg' src={trail.imgSmall} alt={trail.name}></img>
        <h4>{trail.name}</h4>
        <h6>Length: {trail.length + ' miles'}</h6>
        <h6>{trail.location}</h6>

        </div></Link>
        </div>
    }) : 'loading'


    return ( 
    <div className='mainTrails'>
        <div className='container'>
         {/* <div><GoogleMap /></div> */}
            <div>{mappedTrails}</div>
            <p></p>
        <div>


       <div>
           <Pagination
                activePage={this.state.activePage}
                itemsCountPerPage={20}
                totalItemsCount={this.props.trailsList.length}
                pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                onChange={this.handlePageChange}
            />
    </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    trailsList: state.trailsList,
    chooseTrail: state.chooseTrail
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getTrails,
  chooseTrail
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Trails);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through console logging state and found the numbers were returning correctly but once I tried to multiply them they were returning NaN. Reason being is that they were being multiplied as strings, using parseInt on them before multiplying them did the trick.

```
      let { trailsList, chooseTrail } = this.props;
       console.log(trailsList)

      //FOR PAGINATION
      let activePageIndex = parseInt(this.state.activePage, 10);
      let itemsPerPageIndex = parseInt(this.state.itemsPerPage, 10);


        let indexOfLastTrail = activePageIndex * itemsPerPageIndex;
        let indexOfFirstTrail = indexOfLastTrail - itemsPerPageIndex;

      let renderedTrails = trailsList.slice(indexOfFirstTrail, 
indexOfLastTrail);

      let mappedTrails = renderedTrails ?  renderedTrails.map((trail, index) => 
{
          return <div className='trailsContainer'> 
            <Link onClick={() => {chooseTrail(trail.id)}} 
className='trailButton' to={{ pathname:`/trail/${trail.id}`}} 
         key={index}><div>



        <img id='trailImg' src={trail.imgSmall} alt={trail.name}></img>
        <h4>{trail.name}</h4>
        <h6>Length: {trail.length + ' miles'}</h6>
        <h6>{trail.location}</h6>

        </div></Link>
        </div>
    }) : 'loading'
```